# IOS UIwebview, how to know if the user is logged in or not

Tags: ios, authentication, cookies, uiwebview

I'm using a webview, that loads a website that has an authentication page. I want to know if it's possible to know outside the webview if the user is logged in or not ? Do I need to get the cookies from the webview ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: want you see this inside the app?

Comment: yes I want to see if the user is logged in inside the app

Comment: i think you have to use a online DB MySql or what you want and connect the app via JSon ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the best solution.

Comment: you can use a SqlLight inside the app, but you have to take the information of login from your web.